# Yii 1.1 pdf extension not showing png images

Tags: php, pdf, yii

We have a website that is currently on an Ubuntu 16.04 server and we are working on moving to Amazon. The rest of the site (Written in PHP Yii 1.1) is working fine except for the piece that present our reports in PDF format.

The report is written to pdf with no real issue but images show as a red X After some debugging I came to the conclusion that the majority of the images are png images and that is why they do not show. The single jpg image on the report is showing.

How can I get this to work? The html version of the report (that uses different code) gets the image from the same place and that works just fine. I cannot really convert all images because they are generated dynamically.

I read somewhere that pdf does not support png images, REALLY?? Why did it render just fine on the current server?

I do not believe that is is going to help but here is some code used:
main.config:

```
        'ePdf' => array(
        'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
        'params'        => array(
            'mpdf'     => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.mpdf.*',
                'constants'         => array(
                    '_MPDF_TEMP_PATH' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime'),
                ),
                'class'=>'mpdf', // the literal class filename to be loaded from the vendors folder
                'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184
                    'mode'              => '', //  This parameter specifies the mode of the new document.
                    'format'            => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'default_font_size' => 0, // Sets the default document font size in points (pt)
                    'default_font'      => '', // Sets the default font-family for the new document.
                    'mgl'               => 15, // margin_left. Sets the page margins for the new document.
                    'mgr'               => 15, // margin_right
                    'mgt'               => 16, // margin_top
                    'mgb'               => 16, // margin_bottom
                    'mgh'               => 9, // margin_header
                    'mgf'               => 9, // margin_footer
                    'orientation'       => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                )
            ),
        ),
```

Controller:

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('utf-8', 'A4');
$mPDF1->simpleTables = true;
$mPDF1->useSubstitutions = false;
$mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('pdfRXMapFile', array('model' => $model)));
```

Comment: Might help: https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/image-errors.html

Comment: The hint by Alvaro was helpful. I ended up finding the examples that comes with  Yii ePDF and viewing them in a browser that is rendered as a pdf. I saw that all images in the examples were showing except of the alpha images. This helped me to realize that php5-gd was not installed.